# Use of witnessing expansion

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Currently I am new to First order logic, I encountered this concept of witnessing expansion of adding constants in $L$ structure and relate $F.O$ satisfiability to propositional satisfiability. So can some one explain how is it helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [Witness (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witness_(mathematics)): "In mathematical logic, a witness is a specific value $t$ [a *term*] to be substituted for variable $x$ of an existential statement of the form $∃x φ(x)$ such that $φ(t)$ is true."

Comment: I have seen that, but why do we need to add the witnessing terms? how do they help in checking FO satisfiability?

Comment: To expand a FO language $\mathcal L$ is to produce a new language $\mathcal L' = \mathcal L \cup \{ c \}$ where $c$ is a new individual constant added to "witness" a formula $∃xφ(x)$ of the original language.

Comment: You can see *Henkin Constructions* into David Marker, [Model theory: An introduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=3LIPBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA35), Springer (2002), page 35-on.